# Udev rule got erased after executing yum -y update

Tags: networking, yum, udev

I wanted to rename my network interfaces, so I did the following:

**STEP 1:**

added `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` to `/etc/defaults/grub` and then used `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

**STEP 2:**

I added the following rules for each interface to `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="myMacAddress", NAME="newName"
```

**STEP 3:**

I changed NAMEs and DEVICE names and file names in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg*`.

And it worked perfectly (even after reboot), but after executing `yum -y update` everything got erased. Does anybody know what I should do and why it did happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Own `udev-rules` should be located in `/etc/udev/rules.d`

During an update they can be overritten in `/lib/udev/rules.d`

Comment: Hi Bahamut, Would you care to expand the answer a bit more, maybe with a relevant link?

Comment: I'll try. ` The udev rules are read from the files located in the system rules directory /lib/udev/rules.d, in directory /run/udev/rules.d and the local administration directory
       /etc/udev/rules.d.`  The rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d` have the highest priority.  <https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html> I hope this is a Link.